# AngularJS filter to remove a certain regular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am attempting to make an angularJS filter which will remove timestamps that look like this: (##:##:##) or ##:##:##.

This is a filter to remove all letters:

```
.filter('noLetter', function()  {
//this filter removes all letters
        return function removeLetters(string){
        return string.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, " ");
        }
        })
```

This is my attempt to make a filter that removes the time stamps, however it is not working, help is much appreciated.

```
.filter('noStamps', function () {
  return function removeStamps(item) {
  return item.replace(/^\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)$/i, "");
 }
})
```

My goal is for it to delete the timestamps it finds and leave nothing in their place.

edit based on question in comments:
The time stamps are in the text so it would say "this is an example 21:20:19 of what I am 21:20:20 trying to do 21:20:22"

I would want this to be converted into "this is an example of what I am trying to do" by the filter.

Comment: Remove anchors and/or make paren optional? Try `\(?[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)?` no need for i flag, no letters, maybe use g flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\s*\(?\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b\)?/g
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC4kW7/1)

Thre main points:

- The `^`(start of string) and `$`(end of string) anchors should be removed so that the expression becomes unanchored, and can match input text partially.
- Global flag to match all occurrences
- Limiting quantifier `{2}` to shorten the regex (and the use of a shorthand class `\d` helps shorten it, too)
- `\)?` and `\(?` are used with `?`quantifier to match 1 or 0 occurrences of the round brackets.
- `\s*` in the beginning "trims" the result (as the leading whitespace is matched).

JS snippet:

```js
 
var str = 'this is an example (21:20:19) of what I am 21:20:20 trying to do 21:20:22';
var result = str.replace(/\s*\(?\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b\)?/g, '');
document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```